# Unable to use json.loads() due to 'expected string or buffer'

Tags: python, json, typeerror

I've been stuck trying to pull a certain bit from this api response for a while.

my code:

```
payload = {
    'symbol':'RPX-ETH',
    'from':'100603756',
    'to':'9516619507'
}
request = requests.get('https://api.kucoin.com/v1/open/chart/history', 
params=payload)
jdata = json.loads(request)
print jdata['c']
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

The api response only using .json() for reference:

```
{u'c': [0.00024, 0.000171, 0.000163, 0.000151, 0.000159, 0.000164}
```

Comment: try jdata = request.json() print jdata['c']

Comment: Should be jdata = request.json() instead of jdata = json.loads(request).

Comment: The closing `]` is missing. typo?

Comment: @Rakesh that works thanks

Comment: @Sumtinlazy. Your are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[request.json](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)** to access the return data as a dictionary.

Replace

```
jdata = json.loads(request)
print jdata['c']
```

With

```
jdata = request.json() 
print jdata['c']
```

Answer (score 3):

`request` is the whole requests response object. You need to pass `request.body`.

However there is no need to do that at all because `request.json()` does it for you and returns a parsed Python data structure.